# How to instantiate an array with key-value pairs in TypeScript?

Tags: javascript, arrays, typescript

I want to instantiate an array of key-value pairs in one step, but I can't figure out how. Auto-numbering won't work in my use-case. I can only make it work in two steps:

`let army: string[] = [];
army[100] = 'centuria';
army[1000] = 'legion';
...`

What I'd like to be able to do, which is available in most other programming languages:

`let army: string[] = [
    100  => 'centuria',
    1000 => 'legion',
    ...
];`

Is there any way to do this in TypeScript?

***Edit:*** I can't use an object as I need to pass the data to an interface which is expecting an array.

Comment: Do you actually want a sparse array, or do you actually want a key->value object whose keys are numbers?

Comment: @RyanCavanaugh: I want an array, as the keys can change often, making it difficult to define a type for an object. i.e. I want to avoid defining `let army: {100: string, 1000: string, ...}`, as that kinda defeats the purpose.

Comment: I wonder in which other programming languages what you're asking is available? Why isn't a key/value object good for you? why does it defeat the purpose?

Comment: You could write `let army: { [key: number]: string }`. That's why I'm asking.

Comment: @NitzanTomer: It's available in most scripting languages (PHP, Python, etc.)

Comment: @RyanCavanaugh: Ah, I was unaware you could define objects like that. I was also having issues iterating over an object's properties, but that's fixed now. However, I need to pass that data to a component which is expecting an array, so I don't really have a choice. :(

Comment: In php you can have an indexed array which is like a regular array in js, and an associative arrays which are like the js objects. Python has lists and dicts which also are like js array/object

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There's no such functionality in javascript, but you can easily create it:

```
function arrayFactory<T>(obj: { [key: number]: T }): T[] {
    let arr = [];

    Object.keys(obj).forEach(key => {
        arr[parseInt(key)] = obj[key];
    });

    return arr;
}

let arr = arrayFactory({ 100: "centuria", 1000: "legion" });
console.log(arr); // [100: "centuria", 1000: "legion"]
```

([code in playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=function%20arrayFactory%3CT%3E(obj%3A%20%7B%20%5Bkey%3A%20number%5D%3A%20T%20%7D)%3A%20T%5B%5D%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20let%20arr%20%3D%20%5B%5D%3B%0A%0A%20%20%20%20Object.keys(obj).forEach(key%20%3D%3E%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20arr%5BparseInt(key)%5D%20%3D%20obj%5Bkey%5D%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%7D)%3B%0A%0A%20%20%20%20return%20arr%3B%0A%7D%0A%0Alet%20arr%20%3D%20arrayFactory(%7B%20100%3A%20%22centuria%22%2C%201000%3A%20%22legion%22%20%7D)%3B%0Aconsole.log(arr)%3B%20%2F%2F%20%5B100%3A%20%22centuria%22%2C%201000%3A%20%22legion%22%5D))

The question is why not using an object as key/map to store this data?  What different does it make to use an array (which is basically an object itself)?

Comment: Thanks! I think I'll just stick with the two steps though, as it still seems cleaner than creating an object just to convert it to an array.